# Can anyone explain what is the pseudoconcave or pseudoconvex in easier way to me?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

I have searched " pseudoconvex" in wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoconvex_function

However,i still don't understand what is this,the wiki said every convex is pseudoconvex,but the converse is not true . So what is their main difference?can anyone explain it by a figure or easier explanation to me?like this video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fu13eypvDWc&list=PLy7eeFbqDbH3-6zDk3R2F6_-gLRKnv9Zp&index=3&t=260s

Comment: $ f(x)=x+x^3$ is pseudoconvex and non-convex.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner can you tell me why?not just give me an example.i mean because some reason,it is pseudoconvex,not the convex

Answer (score 0):

It is a generalisation of convexity.

A convex differentiable function satisfies $f(y)-f(x) \ge Df(x)(y-x)$, so if $Df(x)(y-x) \ge 0$ then clearly $f(y)-f(x) \ge 0$.

A pseudo-convex function is one that is differentiable and if $Df(x)(y-x) \ge 0$ then $f(y)-f(x) \ge 0$.

Hence any convex function is automatically pseudo-convex.

Comment: what is Df(x) means? can you use a figure to explain this?

Comment: The derivative.

Comment: like this video :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fu13eypvDWc&list=PLy7eeFbqDbH3-6zDk3R2F6_-gLRKnv9Zp&index=3&t=260s

Comment: it seems that f is the function of x and y ,but someone said that $x+x^3$ is pseudoconvex,but it just has one variable